# How to specify default file extension for Oracle's Pro*COBOL precompiler

Tags: oracle, cobol, procobol

Is it possible to configure the default file extension that Oracle's Pro*COBOL precompiler assumes for

```
EXEC SQL INCLUDE filename END-EXEC
```

statements in which there is no filename specified for the include file?

The docs seem specify that in this case - INCLUDE statement without file extension - the precompiler will use the system default file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle support says: no, this is not configurable.
On Windows and Linux, the default extension is .cob.